# Sync secondary name server zones to primary server

Tags: bind, named-conf, plesk

I have two servers with Plesk, unfortunately I'm not a pro, so sorry if my question is stupid. The first server functions as a primary server with with many domains. Before that this server was the primary and the secondary names server.

I had to purchase an other server, with a new license, so I decided I will use it as a secondary name server.

On the primary server I installed the "Slave Manager" extension, and configured it on the primary server using the tutorial at https://devblog.plesk.com/2013/10/slave-dns-and-plesk/.

It looks like everything is ok, when I add a domain on the primary server:

```
transfer of 'domain.es/IN' from 136.xxx.xxx.xxx#53: Transfer completed: 1 messages, 22 records, 519 bytes, 0.012 secs (43250 bytes/sec)
```

On the secondary server I added a new domain, and used DIG to get info about the domain on the primary name server, but unfortunately:

```
NS not responding or not authoritative
```

It looks like the secondary doesn't sync to the primary. Is it the normal behaviour? How can I sync the the records on the secondary server to the primary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal and wanted situation. There is one authoritative server for domain (primary) and slaves gets data from them, but cannot propagate changes to primary. It makes sense - secondary servers are often out of reach of primary admins and you don't want to allow someone other to modify your domain.

But don't worry, there is help for you - you can define second server as primary for that new domain (specification of primary server is domain-based) and your first server as slave of this. See documentation how to do it in plesk.